# Determining Windows local group membership for other than logged-in user with WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying determine if a specified user is a member of a local group on Windows. The user is not the logged-in user.

My approach has been to use NetUserGetLocalGroups and then iterate through the groups to see if the group of interest is listed.

```
   LPGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 pBuf = NULL;
   DWORD dwLevel = 0; 
   DWORD dwFlags = LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT;
   DWORD dwPrefMaxLen = MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH;
   DWORD dwEntriesRead = 0;
   DWORD dwTotalEntries = 0;  
   NET_API_STATUS nStatus = NetUserGetLocalGroups(servernameW, szUserNameW, dwLevel, dwFlags, (LPBYTE*)&pBuf, dwPrefMaxLen, &dwEntriesRead, &dwTotalEntries);
```

This works when szUserNameW is the logged-in user. However, the NetUserGetLocalGroups call fails when szUserNameW is another user, returning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

I am testing this on Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. The logged in user and the user whose group membership is being checked are domain members.

Is there a way for an ordinary user to determine whether another user belongs to a local group? What rights are required for a user to do this look-up?

Comment: Did you try "DomainName\UserName"  or just "UserName"?

Comment: I've been trying DomainName\UserName

Comment: If I try without the domain prefix, NetUserGetLocalGroups returns NERR_UserNotFound

Comment: I guess the "another user" may need elevated privileges to retrieve the information. Did you try by adding the user to "Administrator" group.

Comment: I notice the Windows Control panel in the Computer Management app allows non-Admin users to list local group members. Rather than getting all the groups for a user, perhaps I'll try getting all the users that belong to the group.

Comment: For completeness, if the logged-in user is an Admin, then the look-up succeeds for other users.

Comment: Hmmm..... the code executes with logged in user privileges....Can we force application to Run as admin.